# Spawning multiple python scripts in bash

Tags: python, bash, multiprocessing

I use the below script to spawn multiple python scripts in the server. The argument given to each of the script `l` is different and varies from 0 to 150.

```
for i in `seq 0 9`;
do 
    for j in `seq 0 14`;
    do 
        f=$((i*15))
        l=$((j+f))
        ./script --l ${l} &
    done
    i=0
    for job in `jobs -p`
    do
        pids[${i}]=${job}
        i=$((i+1))
    done
    for pid in ${pids[*]}; do
        wait ${pid}
    done 
done
```

The above syntax spawns 15 python scripts and waits for each of the child processes to finish before spawning the subsequent 15. However, the python script takes little time for some values of `l` and lots of time for other values of `l`. My problem is that, if for a given set of 15 `l` values, the script takes very little time for 14 of them and lots of time for one value of `l`, then the above script waits for the one script to finish before spawning the next 15, which results in many of the cores in the server remaining idle. I was wondering if there is a way to modify the above code to spawn a new child process every time one of them finishes (so that there are 15 child processes running at any given time).

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using the `multiprocessing` library in python? https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
for i in $(seq 150)
do
  while [[ $(jobs | wc -l) -ge 15 ]]
  do
    wait -n $(jobs -p)
  done
  script --l "$i" &
done
```

The idea is that if there are 15 or more jobs, wait till at least one of them finishes till there's not more than 15 running; then spawn a next one. `wait -n` is useful as it will stop waiting when *any* of the mentioned processes exits.